# Hatch fill between while exporting in eps in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, vector-graphics, eps, hatchstyle

In matplotlib while I got error while I was trying to shade few overlapping bands with various hatches (fill_between) and to export in eps format. Is there a solution, keeping the vector format intact?

Comment: Can you provide us with a minimal runnable example that generates the problem, the full backtrace generated, and your os and mpl versions?  I am confused why anyone up-voted this question as it is basically unanswerable in it's current form.

Comment: mpl 1.3.1 supports hatched fill between. But I (ubuntu 12.04) can not export it in eps format. Only pdf can be exported and that appears very faint. No success in converting the pdf to eps. What to do?